# Pergunta com multipla escola em Jquery

Tags: jquery

Queria fazer um esquema tipo questionário. O exemplo mais perto que achei foi esse:
http://quickenloans.github.io/SlickQuiz/

Mas não quero um quiz e nem todo em JS. Quero algo do tipo:

Pergunta
R1
R2
R3
R4

No exemplo a R3 está correta. Caso o user escolha outra que não seja R3 é mostrada uma mensagem falando que está errado e explicando qual é a certa e o pq.

A idéia não é ter pontuação nem nada, apenas uma espécie de sistema de aprendizado.

Comment: Já tentou alguma coisa? Já deu uma olhada ao código do link que colocou? alguma parte especial em que teve dificuldade?

Comment: Sim, todo sistema gira em torno de js. Eu quero algo em HTML puro pra facilitar a indexação dos motores de busca.

Só quero algo em jquery que mostre uma mensagem quando clicada nas opções.

Comment: Ok, consegue fazer o HTML? Se fizer o HTML nós ajudamos na parte de interação (esconder/mostrar/mensagens de erro/etc). Tenha em atenção que o google agora já usa javascript para o SEO...

Comment: Ok.Vou fazer aqui então...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme você solicita na pergunta e nos comentários abaixo dela, algo em HTML puro, que simplesmente mostre a resposta correta, e o motivo.

Desenvolvi um script que se baseia apenas na estrutura HTML das perguntas, sem precisar definir parâmetros, etc...

Veja abaixo:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="pergunta"><span>Pergunta 1?</span>
    <div>Resposta 1</div>
    <div>Resposta 2
         <span>A resposta correta é a 2 por que este span esta dentro dela!</span>
    </div>
    <div>Resposta 3</div>
    <div>Resposta 4</div>
</div>

<div class="pergunta"><span>Pergunta 2?</span>
    <div>Resposta 1</div>
    <div>Resposta 2</div>
    <div>Resposta 3</div>
    <div>Resposta 4
         <span>A resposta correta é a 4 por que este span esta dentro dela!</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jquery:**

```
$('.pergunta div').click(function () {
    if ($(this).find('span').length) {
        $(this).addClass('correta').children('span').prepend(' Correto!!! ').show();
    } else {
        $(this).append(' Resposta errada...').addClass('errada');
        $(this).siblings('div').has('span').addClass('correta').children('span').show();
    }
});
```

Veja funcionando no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/8y49brfc/)

Answer (score 1):

[**EXEMPLO NO JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gkvtvgj1/)

De forma bem simplória:

#### HTML

```
<form>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1" />Resposta 1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="2" />Resposta 2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="3" />Resposta 3</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="4" />Resposta 4</label>
</form>

<div id="message"></div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var respostaQ1 = 3; // Resposta correta

$("input[name=q1]").on("click", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var message = "";

    respostaQ1 == value ? message = "Certo!" : message = "Errado";

    $("#message").html(message);
});
```

A partir desse exemplo, você pode evoluir para atender às suas necessidades. Ao invés de armazenar as respostas em variáveis você pode resgatar isso via Ajax no ato do salvamento (para evitar trapaças).

Comment: Eu preferia ver o Vinny a colocar o seu HTML primeiro antes de haver uma resposta... mais você foi mais rápido. Olhando para o seu código deixo uma sugestão para encurtar: http://jsfiddle.net/gkvtvgj1/1/